# jquery: navigation bar subsubmenu's children slide to the right on hover?

Tags: jquery, navigationbar

With the help of jaychapani, my navigation bar's submenus are sliding up and down well. Now when i hover on subsubmenu1, I want its children to slide to the right. Does anyone know how to do that?

The following is the jquery code to slide up and slide down in the navigation bar.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submenu1,#submenu2").children().hide();

    $("#submenu1,#submenu2").hover( 
        function(){//onmouseover 
            $(this).children("ul").slideDown(); 
        }, 
        function(){//onmouseout 
            $(this).children("ul").slideUp(); 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

css for navigation bar:

```
    #navbar{
/*  height:10%;
*/  width:900px;
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#ffffff;
    float:left;
    margin-top:2%;
    }

ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li{
float:left;
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

html code for navigation bar:

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li id="submenu1">Register Company
        <ul>
            <li id="subsubmenu1">New Sendirian Berhad Registration
                <ul>
                    <li>Company Price</li>
                    <li>Register New Company</li>
                    <li>Steps to Incorporate</li>


    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="submenu2">Buy Company
            <ul>
                <li>Sendirian Berhad Ready Made Companies in Malaysia</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put `id="submenu1" id="submenu2"` on `<ul>` it should be on `<li>`

like

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li id="submenu1">Register Company
        <ul>
            <li>New Sendirian Berhad Registration
                <ul>
                    <li>Company Price</li>
                    <li>Register New Company</li>
                    <li>Steps to Incorporate</li>


                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="submenu2">Buy Company
        <ul>
            <li>Sendirian Berhad Ready Made Companies in Malaysia</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GdvW3/2/)